# find unique records within a table

Tags: sql, database, unique

```
one table a= {el1, el2}
where el1 is 1..10, el2 is {5..15}.
```

In the table records are like `[el1, el2]` 
and also some record `[el2, el1]`, that is they are the same, just in different collumns.

What is the best way to fetch unique el1, el2 elements? (record 1,2 is the same as 2,1)

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure that there's a more elegant solution but right now I can't think of it.  The first part finds rows where you can't find a match if you reverse the columns.  The second finds rows where you can find a match if you reverse the columns - and deals with the [el1, el2] pair that has the same value in each column

```
select t1.el1, t1.el2
from @tbl t1
where not exists (select * from @tbl t2 where t2.el1 = t1.el2 and t2.el2 = t1.el1)

union

select t1.el1, t1.el2
from @tbl t1
where exists (select * from @tbl t2 where t2.el1 = t1.el2 and t2.el2 = t1.el1 and t2.el1 <= t1.el1)
```

Comment: I came up with a little different solution, made a union, that is table1(a,b) table2(a,b) select a,b from t1 where a<b union select b,a from t2 where a<b. Since in my case it's number, i think it worked out, with text it should work as well

Comment: Well why not post it to help others in the future?

Answer (score 0):

To scrub the data (mop the floor...):

```
SELECT el1, el2
  FROM YourTable
UNION
SELECT el2 AS el1, el1 AS el2
  FROM YourTable;
```

To prevent data corruption from reoccurring (...fix the leak):

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable ADD
    CHECK ( el1 < el2 );
```